# Append html after Link (to show a link preview)

Tags: javascript

i have a link preview that work with linkpreview API

here the Jsfiddle with demo: https://jsfiddle.net/e4wdcjgz/

i need some help to make these adjustment:

- javascript must catch all the link inside the div, and append after that the result

Here the demo of my actual situation:

https://jsfiddle.net/3xznoLhj/

here actual code:

```
var data = { key: "my-api-key", q: "https://tomshw.it" };

fetch("https://api.linkpreview.net", {
  method: "POST",
  mode: "cors",
  body: JSON.stringify(data)
})
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then((response) => {
    document.getElementById("mytitle").innerHTML = response.title;
    document.getElementById("mydescription").innerHTML = response.description;
    document.getElementById("myimage").src = response.image;
    document.getElementById("myurl").innerHTML = response.url;
  });
```

p.s. the element are not created at moment because i do not know how can i append the result to every link

Answer (score 0):

- What i understand of you is that you wants to append html after a link element and you can do that with `element.insertAdjacentHTML(position, html)` Method this method has 4 Values to choose the elements position `"afterbegin"`, `"afterend"`, `"beforebegin"`,  `"beforeend"`

> Here's an example

```
var htm = `<h2>Request is finished</h2>
<div> Response is `+ 123 + `</div>`;
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", htm);
```

Comment: exactly i want to append the result of the script after every link (with the matched result obviously)